# random_shift and flow_from_directory in keras preprocessing

Tags: python, keras

I have two questions and both are related to image.py in preprocessing.py

1) The  image shift uses alternative dimension to decide tx and ty.
why does tx decide the height changes. Should it not be working on width.

```
   h, w = x.shape[row_axis], x.shape[col_axis]
     tx = np.random.uniform(-hrg, hrg) * h
     ty = np.random.uniform(-wrg, wrg) * w
     x = apply_affine_transform(x, tx=tx, ty=ty, channel_axis=channel_axis,
    fill_mode=fill_mode, cval=cval)
```

2) I tried to use two different methods to extract bottle neck features on flower17 datasets. There are 17 classes and each labels have 80 images.The first approach loads every file and calculate bottleneck features.

```
 for i, label in enumerate(train_labels):
        cur_path = train_path + "/" + label
        count = 1
        for image_path in glob.glob(cur_path + "/*.jpg"):
            img = image.load_img(image_path, target_size=image_size)
            x = image.img_to_array(img)
            x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
            x = preprocess_input(x)
            feature = model.predict(x)
            flat = feature.flatten()
            features.append(flat)
            labels.append(label)
            print ("[INFO] processed - " + str(count))
        count += 1
    print ("[INFO] completed label - " + label)
```

The second one uses ImageDataGenerator and flow_from_directory

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function = preprocess_input)  
generator  = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
            train_path,
            target_size=image_size,
            shuffle = "false",
            class_mode='categorical',
            batch_size=batchsize)

nb_train_samples = len(generator.filenames)  
num_classes = len(generator.class_indices) 
predict_size_train = int(math.ceil(nb_train_samples / batchsize))
label_map = (generator.class_indices)
label_map = dict((v,k) for k,v in label_map.items()) #flip 
for i in range(predict_size_train):
    x, y = next(generator)
    features.append(model.predict(x))
    labels.append(y)
features = np.concatenate(features)

labels = np.argmax(np.concatenate(labels),axis=1)
labels = [label_map[x] for x in labels]
```

Both the above methods use only preprocess_input. I notice there are exactly 80 labels for each class in both the approaches, but once I compare those row features with this function; I find approx less than 50% features matches.

```
def compareFeatures(A, B):
    nrows, ncols = A.shape
    dtype={'names':['f{}'.format(i) for i in range(ncols)],
       'formats':ncols * [A.dtype]}

    C = np.intersect1d(A.view(dtype), B.view(dtype))

    C = C.view(A.dtype).reshape(-1, ncols)
    return C
```

I was getting 2-3% difference  in  classification result with both the approaches. But both the approach use load_img and img_to_array so there shouldn't  be any difference